# Python: solve linear system in GF(2)

Tags: python, linear-algebra, modulo

I have a linear system Ax=L where:

A(m,m) is a np.array
L(1,m) is a np.array

Their elements are either 1 or 0. I want to find the array x, composed exclusively by 1 and 0 elements that solves the system. I'm new to Python and I don't know how to work in a GF(2). I simply tried this solution:

```
from scipy import linalg as la

sln = np.la.solve(A, L) % 2
```

But the solution is not made by only 0 and 1 but other numbers appear. If anybody has any alternative or suggestion please let me know.

Comment: I think that the linear algebra module by default over reals (maybe complex?). Given that `%2` doesn't give the value of `0` or `1` it gives a number in the range `[0, 2)` I think you might have to do a different system altogether to solver GF(2). Maybe Sage can do it? http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'm currently trying to find another way, and this paper might have an answer: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/factoring/fastgauss.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "another way"? Another way using vanilla Python?

Comment: Finally I wrote a piece of code for an effective gaussian elimination in Python with binary elements (I used dtype=bool_ ). I wrote it in order to avoid division and problems with the many False-like elements. The real problem I encountered is that many matrices I was working with turned out to be singular and the system dependent. But I guess infinite solutions are better than none.